# Spring CriteriaBuilder search enum by it's name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

When I'm trying to search enum by his name with [`Specification`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) in my DB using [`Spring @Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [HELLO] did not match expected type [application.springEnum.Hello (n/a)]
```

But in the DB the enum saved as `VARCHAR(255)` so why I can search the enum with `String`, why It's need to by a Enum type?

***DTO class***

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DTO {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Hello helloEnum; // My Enum
}
```

**DataBase connector**

```
@Repository
public interface Connector extends JpaRepository<DTO, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DTO> {
}
```

**Starter**

```
@Component
public class Starter {
    @Autowired
    private Connector connector;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // Create DTO entity
        DTO dto = DTO.builder()
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .helloEnum(Hello.HELLO)
                .build();
        // Save the entity in the db
        connector.save(dto);

        // Search by the name, here I get the excpetion
        List<DTO> result = connector.findAll((root, query, cb) ->
                cb.equal(root.get("helloEnum"), "HELLO")
        );
    }
}
```

I would appreciate for an explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to compare `Enum` and `String`.

Try this way:

```
List<DTO> result = connector.findAll((root, query, cb) ->
                cb.equal(root.get("helloEnum"), Hello.HELLO);
```

I will try to provide some explanations why this is happening. Hibernate fetches `ResultSet` from Database to `Class` signature using `Reflection`.

Observing stacktrace you will see something like:

> org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:486)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]

Hibernate performs a bunch of validations before setting a parameter.

Here is the last method which initializes a root cause for `Exception`:

```
public <P> void validate(Type paramType, Object bind, TemporalType temporalType) {
        if ( bind == null || paramType == null ) {
            // nothing we can check
            return;
        }
        final Class parameterType = paramType.getReturnedClass();
        if ( parameterType == null ) {
            // nothing we can check
            return;
        }

        if ( Collection.class.isInstance( bind ) && !Collection.class.isAssignableFrom( parameterType ) ) {
            // we have a collection passed in where we are expecting a non-collection.
            //      NOTE : this can happen in Hibernate's notion of "parameter list" binding
            //      NOTE2 : the case of a collection value and an expected collection (if that can even happen)
            //          will fall through to the main check.
            validateCollectionValuedParameterBinding( parameterType, (Collection) bind, temporalType );
        }
        else if ( bind.getClass().isArray() ) {
            validateArrayValuedParameterBinding( parameterType, bind, temporalType );
        }
        else {
            if ( !isValidBindValue( parameterType, bind, temporalType ) ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        String.format(
                                "Parameter value [%s] did not match expected type [%s (%s)]",
                                bind,
                                parameterType.getName(),
                                extractName( temporalType )
                        )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

The method `private static boolean isValidBindValue(Class expectedType, Object value, TemporalType temporalType)` which has a bunch of checks retuns `false` because your expected type is `class com.whatever.Hello` and value to check is `HELLO` what is `String`, but `Enum` type and `String` are incompatible!

If you will put proper `Enum` in your search criteria, validation will pass because `private static boolean isValidBindValue(Class expectedType, Object value, TemporalType temporalType)` contains `isInstance` check which will pass:

```
else if ( expectedType.isInstance( value ) ) {
    return true;
}
```

After all the checks Hibernate extracts values from `ResultSet` and builds the `List`, in this particular case, elements of `List` are fetched using reflection.

Comment: I know, but in the database it's save as varchar

Comment: @Daniel Taub please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Is there any way to use criteria builder Like method with enum?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Main {
enum Hello {
    HELLO
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello hello = Hello.HELLO;
    System.out.println(hello.toString().equals("HELLO")); //true
    System.out.println("HELLO".equals(hello.toString())); //true
    System.out.println(hello.toString() == "HELLO"); //true
    System.out.println(hello.equals("HELLO")); //false
    System.out.println("HELLO".equals(hello)); //false
//        System.out.println(hello == "HELLO"); //incompatible types
}
}
```

Not completely sure but equal() parameters have to be in same type.

```
root.get("helloEnum")
```

is instance of Hello

```
"HELLO"
```

is instance of String.

There is no automagic toString() cast on enum here.
Just to be sure try:

```
// Search by the name, here I get the excpetion
    List<DTO> result = connector.findAll((root, query, cb) ->
            cb.equal(root.get("helloEnum").toString(), "HELLO")
    );
```

Comment: About how it's represented in database, it's ORM thing.

Comment: does not event compile